# R: How default argument is passed to a function?

Tags: r, default-arguments

In the .GlobalEnv, I defined the following variable and function

```
x = 0; 
foo <- function(t=x) {x=1; t}
```

When I called the function in the following ways

```
foo() # gives 1
foo(t=x) # gives 0
```

Can anyone help explain this? Thanks!!!

Comment: In the first case, the function knows it needs to pass `x` to `t`.  It is looking for `x` in its lexical scope and finds `x=1`. In the second case, you pass `x=0` from the global environment, thus  it doesn't look for it in the lexical scope again and passes it straight to `t`. Nice question though.

Comment: More reading on [lazy evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#function-arguments).

Comment: @rawr, Have you seen [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274834/coursera-questions/274835)? :)

Comment: did you see coursera?  LOL

Comment: I didn't know this. I'm glad I saw it here before it messed me up one day.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, thanks for the answer. I have two more questions about lexical scope and parameter passing.

Comment: @DavidArenburg,
**1.** Does the argument list of the function has the same lexical scope as the function body? What positions is the argument list lies? At the beginning or the end?
**2.** In the 2nd case, seems x is not set to 0 when passing, as 
`foo <- function(t=x) {x=1; eval(substitute(t))}` 
gives 1 when called by `foo(t=x)`. So when is x evaluated? 
Thanks again!

Comment: @Gregor,Thanks for the link, it is helpful!!

Comment: @DavidArenburg, sorry to bother you again, but I just find the answer for my 2nd question in [lazy evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#function-arguments) recommended by Gregor.

Answer (score 1):

To make the comment into an answer:

In the first case, the function knows it needs to pass `x` to `t`. It is looking for `x` in its lexical scope and finds `x=1`. In the second case, you pass `x=0` from the global environment, thus it doesn't look for it in the lexical scope again and passes it straight to `t`.